# How to load resources faster / at the same time with JavaScript's XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, http, download, request, xmlhttprequest

I use the following code to load some resources:

```
var currentIndex = 0;

var resources = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg"];

function LoadComplete() {
  console.log('Load complete!');
}

function Load(res) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.open("GET", `http://myapi.com/${ res }`, true);

  req.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      req.onreadystatechange = null;

      if (this.status === 200) {
        currentIndex++;

        if( currentIndex === resources.length) {
          LoadComplete();
        } else {
          Load(resources[currentIndex];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Load(resources[currentIndex]);
```

Is there a way I can do it faster? Maybe loading all resources at the same time and maybe adding an `else` block to check if `this.status === 200`?:

```
  if (this.status === 200) {
    currentIndex++;

    if( currentIndex === resources.length) {
      LoadComplete();
    } else {
      Load(resources[currentIndex];
    }
  } else {
    Load(res); // Is this safe?
  }
```

But I'm unsure if that is "thread" safe. If I just, instead of calling `Load` inside `Load`, keep the check tho if has all the resources?

```
for(var i in resources) {
  Load(resources[i]
}
```

Won't `res` in `Load` be anything else than the one that came in and failed as it might take 2s to fail, and by then the for loop is done?

Answer (score 1):

You can start loading all of them at the same time (the browser handles concurrent requests and their limits for you) and just run the required logic inside `LoadComplete` when the last one finishes loading by changing your logic a little bit:

```
let totalLoaded = 0;

const resources = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'];
const attempts = {};

function LoadComplete() {
  // Called for all of them, but condition only satisfied when the last
  // one finishes loading:

  if (++totalLoaded === resources.length) console.log('load complete!')
}

function Load(res) {
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {    
      req.onreadystatechange = null;

      if (this.status === 200) {
        // Resouce loaded just fine:
        LoadComplete();
      } else {
        // Resource load failed, let's retry up to 3 times:
        const resourceAttempts = attempts[res] || 0;

        if (resourceAttempts === 3) {
          // Already tried 3 times and still failed, so we assume we can't
          // load this resouce and call `LoadComplete` anyway:

          LoadComplete();
        } else {
          // Increment the attempts counter for this resource...:
          attempts[res] += resourceAttempts + 1;

          // And try to load it again:
          Load(res);
        }
      } 

    }
  }

  req.open('GET', `http://myapi.com/${ res }`, true);
}

// Start loading all of them in parallel:

resources.map(resource => Load(resource);
```

However, note that if any of them fails, let's say the server sends a `404` or `500`, then you will never execute that logic, so you might want to only check for `this.readyState === 4`.

Alternatively, as you point out, you could check for status codes other than `200` and handle that separately. You can call `Load` again for the same resource, but you need a per-resource counter to make sure you don't do that indefinitely, as the resource might actually be permanently gone, so you are always going to get the same result.

Comment: Thank you Danzinger. But would it not be better to add a "else" to that if in Load? I dont see how you catch failed Loads to try to load them again?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to in the last paragraph. I have updated the example with some basic retry logic.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are trying to cache the images using ajax.

First thing you can better add hidden image tags to the body and let browser handle the request and when you need just reuse the html element you just created.

About the thread safety:
Everything in javascript is threadsafe because javascript runs on a single thread.
Loading images is done behind the scenes by the browser yes but the js functions you wrote will run in a queue.

Finally about the loading speed:
Browsers limit concurrent requests but unless you have a 100 images and want to show them at the same time this makes no problem because the browser will anyway load at least 10 images in parallel. Speed here is really the matter of your internet speed.
If you want to speed things up and reduce the number of connections however you can always use HTTP/2 on your server to serve multiple things over a single request.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you don't have to worry about thread safety (In fact, JS codes are single-threaded if you don't use workers.).
Just load the resources without checking.